# how do I fix this error: psql: /usr/pgsql-13/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

**Background:**

I'm attempting to download and follow a github project here: https://github.com/dannibla/nodejs-postgresql.

**Goal:**

The goal is to create a working API skeleton server with a postgres database.

I followed the instructions in the blog I found here: https://medium.com/@dannibla/connecting-nodejs-postgresql-f8967b9f5932

When I attempted to run the project, I then received an error message (*that* error message is completely different than this message that I'm receiving when I try to connect manually to the postgres database).

**Steps to recreate:**

When I attempt to connect manually to the postgres db, I follow these steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Switch user to postgres

   ```
    su postgres
   ```
3. Enter password for postgres user
4. receive new cursor prompt:

   ```
    bash-4.4$
   ```
5. Type "psql" to start giving sql commands

   ```
    psql
   ```
6. Receive error message and output:

   ```
    psql: /usr/pgsql-13/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)

    psql: /usr/pgsql-13/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)

    could not change directory to "/home/larry": Permission denied

    psql (10.15, server 13.2)

    WARNING: psql major version 10, server major version 13.

    Some psql features might not work.

    Type "help" for help.


    postgres=#
   ```

**Next Steps:**

Need to identify cause of this version warning message and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using Linux.

You installed some PostgreSQL packages from the PostgreSQL web site and some from your Linux distribution. These were not built in the same way, so the `psql` executable which you have from one source does not work together with the client shared library (libpq) from the other source.

Uninstall all PostgreSQL packages from your distribution and use only the packages from the PostgreSQL web site.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have multiple versions installed from different command or packages which are clashing.

```
rpm -qa|grep postgres
```

If you have amazon linux-2 then use above command or change the package manager according to your linux system.

it will list all the extra packages.

then select which are not needed and remove it

for me:

```
rpm remove postgresql12-libs-12.17-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
```

It will solve your problem.